# Change foundation alert close button to avoid removing from dom?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is there a way without modifying the Zurb Foundation library to alter their [`alert`](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) close button behavior so that it doesn't remove the DOM element?

I am using a client-side MVC that assumes that templated DOM elements don't delete themselves, and instead rely on the MVC library's ability to hide or conditionally display content.

I've tried hooking into `$(...).on('close.fndtn.alert', function(event) { ...`, and the hook is being fired, but `event.preventDefault();` doesn't stop foundation from deleting the element.

Alternately, if there isn't an easy way to hook in and cancel the close without a monkey patch - is there a way to reuse the style of the close button, but not hook into the alert component's close functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to hook into their JS, but I figured out by reading their SASS customization part of the [`alert` docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/alert_boxes.html) how to copy the close button style, but rename the attribute:

```
.alert-box {
  .dismiss {  // renamed from "close" so I can provide my own hooks
    @include alert-close();
  }
}
```

I can now hook into this button's behavior myself and provide my own dismissal handler that won't stomp on the DOM.